# MySQL binary logs will not start

Tags: mysql, logging, database-replication, mariadb, binary-log

In-Short: My binary logs aren't starting even though log-bin is set and specified.  I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have a MariaDB instance running as a service on windows that I am attempting to replicate to a MariaDB instance on a Ubuntu machine.  I am using MySQL workbench 6.0 as much as I can to manage everything, and following the instructions from Oracle here for setting up master-slave replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

I have made it to the fourth chapter, where I allegedly have the master and slave both configured, and I am about to read-lock the master tables for an initial data dump to the slave before I start up replication.  So I flushed the tables with read lock and checked the master status:

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

That last line didn't return any binary log information.  Checking further, I ran:

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

and an error message confirmed that:

```
Error Code: 1381. You are not using binary logging
```

Master Config is like this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir = "C:/mysql/data"
port=3306
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1535M
innodb_log_file_size=50M
feedback=ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
log-bin-index = "C:/mysql/logs/log-bin.index"
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

[client]
port=3306
```

How do I make sure the binary logs are rolling so I can continue with this?

Comment: This would be helpful http://geeksterminal.com/mysql-error-1381-hy000-you-are-not-using-binary-logging-resolved/1218/

Comment: Thanks, but are all of those fields really necessary?  I might want to access the db from a couple different machines, and replicate more than just one db.  If I understand how those work correctly.

Comment: Also, this didn't seem to have an effect.  I made sure all of those fields were specified in my.ini and restarted the server, but still no dice.

Comment: This may sound obvious, but have you tried restarting your mysql service? And, have you checked your mysql error log?